# Grounds as a reason for

Tags: grammar, articles, plural-forms

I have a few questions on the word "grounds".

1) Is it correct to us "grounds" with **is**? Or is it not correct but still acceptable in colloquial speech?

> **Is** there any grounds to do that?

2) Is there any significant difference between:

> **Is** there any ground to do it?
>   **Are** there any grounds to do it?

3) Is using the article "a" with "ground" wrong?

> Is there **a** ground to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Check the definition of [ground](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/ground) senses 5 and 6.

Sense 5 -

> 5) any particular area of reference, discussion, work, etc.; topic; subject   ⇒ "arguments covering the same ground"

here *ground* can be singular.

Sense 6 -

> 6) ([often pl.]) basis; foundation

Your usage is sense 6, usually plural. So it would be correct to say:

> Are there any grounds to do it?